# Как отключить visible для com объектов, при открытых файлах

Tags: python, python-3.x, com

Имеется код

```
import win32com.client
import os
try:
    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if not file.endswith(".doc"):
                continue
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
            doc = app.Documents.Open(fullpath, Visible=False)
            content = doc.Content.Text
            print(content)
            doc.Close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Цель получить следующее:

При обработке `.doc` файлов не показывать их открытие на мониторе, если на момент начала обработки уже открыт Word, то чтобы эти файлы не закрывались.

Этот код практически и решает эту задачу, но только если изначально открытых вордовских файлов нету, иначе `Visible=False` при открытии документов в com-интерфейсе игнорируется.

Comment: Есть "обходной" путь - запустить процесс от другого пользователя. Есть в Винде такая командочка - `runas`. Причем у нее есть ключ, чтобы разок пароль этого пользователя ввести, а потом уже без пароля запустится. Только учтите, что текущий каталог у этого пользователя будет другой, возможно, так что результаты такого запуска в файл пишите и путь к программе питон тоже.

Comment: Такой путь не подходит :(